# OpenGL ES tutorial--LessonOneRenderer not recognizing Renderer interface methods

Tags: android, eclipse, opengl-es-2.0

I've been following the OpenGL ES tutorial at http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/, and have made sure it lines up with the example given, but for some reason the compiler is giving errors for each of the overridden methods in the LessonOneRenderer class. When I get rid of the @Override for each one of them, they are not called at all and the program displays a blank screen.

Why is this class not recognizing the methods from its implemented interface?

LessonOneRenderer

```
package com.aft.glone;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.os.SystemClock;

public class LessonOneRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
private final FloatBuffer mTriangle1Vertices;
//private final FloatBuffer mTriangle2Vertices;
//private final FloatBuffer mTriangle3Vertices;
private int mMVPMatrixHandle;
private int mPositionHandle;
private int mColorHandle;

private final int mBytesPerFloat=4;

private float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] mModelMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];

private final int mStrideBytes = 7 * mBytesPerFloat;
private final int mPositionOffset = 0;
private final int mPositionDataSize = 3;
private final int mColorOffset = 3;
private final int mColorDataSize = 4;

public LessonOneRenderer()
{
    final float[] triangle1VerticesData = {
        //X, Y, Z
        //R, G, B, A
        -0.5f, -0.25f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

        0.5f, -0.25f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

        0.0f, 1.559016994f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};

mTriangle1Vertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(triangle1VerticesData.length *       mBytesPerFloat)
        .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();

mTriangle1Vertices.put(triangle1VerticesData).position(0);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config)
{
GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
final float eyeX = 0.0f;
final float eyeY = 0.0f;
final float eyeZ = 1.5f;

final float lookX = 0.0f;
final float lookY = 0.0f;
final float lookZ = -5.0f;

final float upX = 0.0f;
final float upY = 1.0f;
final float upZ = 0.0f;

Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);

final String vertexShader =
        "uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;  \n"
        + "attribute vec4 a_Position;   \n"
        + "attribute vec4 a_Color;  \n"
        + "varying vec4 v_Color;    \n"
        + "void main()  \n"
        + "{    \n"
        + " v_Color = a_Color;  \n"
        + " gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix * a_Position; \n"
        + "}    \n";
final String fragmentShader = 
        "precision mediump float;   \n"
        + "varying vec4 v_Color;    \n"
        + "void main()  \n"
        + "{    \n"
        + " gl_FragColor = v_Color; \n"
        + "}    \n";

int vertexShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
if (vertexShaderHandle != 0)
{
    GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShaderHandle, vertexShader);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShaderHandle);
    final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGetShaderiv(vertexShaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);
    if (compileStatus[0] == 0)
    {
        GLES20.glDeleteShader(vertexShaderHandle);
        vertexShaderHandle = 0;
    }
}

if (vertexShaderHandle == 0)
{
    throw new RuntimeException("Error creating vertex shader.");
}

int fragmentShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

if (fragmentShaderHandle != 0)
{
    GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShaderHandle, fragmentShader);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShaderHandle);
    final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGetShaderiv(fragmentShaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);
    if (compileStatus[0] == 0)
    {
        GLES20.glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderHandle);
        fragmentShaderHandle = 0;
    }
}

if (fragmentShaderHandle == 0)
{
    throw new RuntimeException("Error creating fragment shader.");
}

int programHandle = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
if (programHandle != 0)
{
    GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, vertexShaderHandle);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, fragmentShaderHandle);
    GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 0, "a_Position");
    GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programHandle,  1, "a_Color");
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(programHandle);
    final int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGetProgramiv(programHandle, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
    if (linkStatus[0] == 0)
    {
        GLES20.glDeleteProgram(programHandle);
        programHandle = 0;
    }
}

if (programHandle == 0)
{
    throw new RuntimeException("Error creating program.");
}

mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");
mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "a_Position");
mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "a_Color");
GLES20.glUseProgram(programHandle);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height)
{
GLES20.glViewport(0,  0, width, height);
final float ratio = (float)width/height;
final float left = -ratio;
final float right = ratio;
final float bottom = -1;
final float top = 1;
final float near = 1;
final float far = 10;
Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused)
{
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 10000L;
float angleInDegrees = (360.0f / 10000.0f) * ((int)time);
Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, angleInDegrees, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
drawTriangle(mTriangle1Vertices);
 }

private void drawTriangle(final FloatBuffer aTriangleBuffer)
{
aTriangleBuffer.position(mPositionOffset);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, mPositionDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
        mStrideBytes, aTriangleBuffer);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
aTriangleBuffer.position(mColorOffset);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mColorHandle, mColorDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
        mStrideBytes, aTriangleBuffer);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to import `android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;` ?

I'm not sure if that's needed if you import GLSurfaceView, but I checked on my own renderer and it includes that import.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to Java compiler version 1.6 should fix the compilation errors, but not having the @Override shouldn't prevent the methods from being called, at least as long as you called setRenderer(...) on the GLSurfaceView from your Activity.

Comment: Switching to 1.6 didn't fix the problem.